# Shell script problem

Tags: python, scripting, linux, osx

In my python script in my .blend file, I run a shell script but the script doesn't work properly when calling it from blender using `os.system'(~/Desktop/./run-test.sh')` although when I run it from terminal using `~/Desktop/./run-test.sh` the script runs and executes properly. This is caused when I use `yes |` in the copy command which makes blender hangs up and the computer starts getting very busy and I have to force quit blender, although this doesn't happen when running the script from terminal. Any thoughts please?

This is my script:

```
import bpy
import os


bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(radius=1, view_align=False, enter_editmode=False, location=(0, 0, 0), layers=(True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False))

os.system('~/Desktop/./run-test.sh')

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_monkey_add(radius=1, view_align=False, enter_editmode=False, location=(0, 0, 0), layers=(True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False))
```

And this is my shell script:

```
cd /Users/UserA/Test/
for entry in "./"/*.txt
do
  yes | cp $entry test.txt #### <-- using yes | hangs up blender
  echo Finished

done
```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, but If possible avoid calling an app/bash, it's unsave in most cases... I'd suggest copy the file with python. Otherwise you *should* use `subprocess` module since python3 instead, great bash call example over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python). To support other platforms [this snippet](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.platform) is useful. However, that can end up in [a lot of conditions](https://github.com/RayMairlot/Batch-Render-Tools/issues/1#issuecomment-238106183) to call a simple command.

Comment: @p2or thanks for your comment. So how I can call and run myscript.sh using `subprocess`? I'm using macos

Comment: Noooo. It's just `subprocess.Popen("your commands".split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` as the first stackoverflow answer suggests or `subprocess.Popen('test.sh', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`.

Comment: @p2or I've tried this `subprocess.Popen(['sh','~/Desktop/./run-test.sh'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` and it works fine but it doesn't display the `echo`'s in my shell script, also I noticed that the next line in my python script after the subprocess line is executed without waiting for the subprocess to finish. Any thoughts?

Comment: Rough draft (untested): https://gist.github.com/p2or/8e137d85898e2d93f394ae267acd1e6e, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837214/python-popen-command-wait-until-the-command-is-finished @Tak

Comment: @p2or Thank you very much. I've used `subprocess.call(['sh','~/Desktop/./run-test.sh'])` instead of `.Popen` so that the next line in my python script is not executed until the shell script finishes and it works fine. The only thing now is that the cube doesn't appear in the scene until the shell script is executed, not sure why?

Comment: Yes, `call()` blocks the execution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071866/non-blocking-subprocess-call, btw: We should avoid discussions in comments. Can you remove your comments to keep it clean here? We can chat tomorrow if you like to...? @Tak